# Simple coroutine leaking with GCC 10

Tags: c++, gcc, c++20

Consider the following simple coroutine, which tracks its construction and destruction:

```cpp
#include <coroutine>
#include <iostream>

struct simple {
  static inline int x = 0;
  int id = 0;
  simple() : id{ x++ } { std::cout << id << " constructed\n"; }
  simple(simple&&) : id{ x++ } { std::cout << id << " move constructed\n"; }
  ~simple() { std::cout << id << " destructed\n"; }

  struct promise_type {
    simple get_return_object() { return {}; }
    void return_void() {}
    void unhandled_exception() { std::terminate(); }
    auto initial_suspend() noexcept { return std::suspend_never{}; }
    auto final_suspend() noexcept { return std::suspend_never{}; }
  };
};

simple f() { co_return; }

int main() {
  f();
}
```

When compiling with GCC 10.1, the output is:

```
0 constructed
1 move constructed
1 destructed
```

—notably, id `0` is never destructed. This is true even with GCC trunk.

Is there something I've done wrong here, some hidden UB or the like? Or is GCC at fault here?

As a comparison, I tried using Clang's experimental coroutine support, and got

```
0 constructed
0 destructed
```

which is closer to what I was expecting. I also get this "correct" output even in GCC if I comment out the move constructor in the coroutine object.

Live example: https://godbolt.org/z/UQVURi

Comment: That is certainly a bug of this experimental implementation of coroutines. You should post a bug report.

Comment: @Oliv I suspected so, and as I've struggled to parse the relevant sections of the standard I am more convinced you are correct. I will post a report soon — thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Oliv mentioned, it appears this is just a bug with GCC's experimental coroutine support. A ticket has been raised [here](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=95477).